# WebSphere Application Server 7.x and IHS 7.x url redirect to static page in htdocs

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, httpserver, ibmhttpserver

I tried all possible ways googling and finally ended up to post a question here.

We have 2 application server nodes and IHS configured on same nodes. Application is deployed on application server cluster members on the respective application server nodes.

We do have configured static page for maintainence activities. But we got a tricky situation here.

1. The application server and IHS has to serve the request. (Application, the application servers and webservers will be up and running)
2. In the application, we have a specific URL, when user hits that specific url, that should be redirected to static page in htdocs. However and whatever the way user tries to access specific url, only static page has to pop up.

There is mod_rewrite module I know, but whatever the scenarios I tried I couldn't configure it. Any solution or suggestion with example, please?

Note: We can't code it at application level.

Comment: What are some of the rules that you have tried?

Comment: Your requirement is not too clear. You just want to intercept a request for a single URL and send it to a static maintenance page if that maintenance page exists on the filesystem?  

Do you have any applications mapped to /* (you can tell in plugin-cfg.xml)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I  tried with rewrite conditon and rewrite rules. But nothing seems to be working :( How can we do in plugin-cfg.xml? :/

Comment: there are many examples that were suggesting to rewrite entire application to maintainence. But my requirement is, specific url in application has to be redirected to static page when request comes for specific url.

Comment: You will want to use a rewrite rule in the IHS configuration making sure that the rewrite rule takes place before the plugin picks up the request. Can you post a couple of things that you tried?

Answer (score -1):

I guess Mod-rewrite is the only option for you.
Prefer not to setup anything in plugin-cfg.xml

ReWriteEngine on
ReWriteRule Pattern Substitution